# How to catch an error in Angular HTTPClient.post() while using generics

Tags: angular

This question has been asked about million trillion times on SO, but none of the post answer my question. So I am asking it again.

Following is my method (in a `service`), which makes a post request.

```
  makePostReq<T>(reqObj: {url:string, body:any, headerData?:any}): Observable<T>{
    let headers = this.createHeaders(reqObj.headerData);
    return this.httpClient.post<T>(reqObj.url, reqObj.body, {headers:headers})
      .catch((e: any ) => {
        console.log(e);
        this.utilityService.showErrorToaster(e);
      });
  }
```

This method, expects to catch an `HTTPError`, then log it and then show user a toaster/alert informing about the error.

**Problem:**

Above code gives this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(e: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<T>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
```

**I already know:**

I perfectly know why I am getting this error. I know that catch is supposed to return an Object of type `Observable<T>`, but I dont have anything to return which is of type `T`. Returning `Observable.of(null)` doesnt work either.
I also know if I remove generic `<T>`, I will not get this compilation error.

**My Question:**

How do I make above code work, without compromising on `generics`.

Comment: What about `return Observable.throw(e);`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole idea of catching the error inside `makePostReq<T>(...)` is misleading.

Here is why.

Firstly, by returning `Observable<T>` we are saying our method will emit values of type `T` at some point (when the http call inside responds). If we handle the error inside `makePostReq<T>(...)` you will have to emit a fake instance of `T` (for example, `null`) to satisfy our compiler. This means you will have to handle this too in your callers by filtering out `null`, (something like `makePostReq<string>(...).pipe(filter(str => str !== null))`) which means essentially you have handled the error twice, when you can just handle the exception in the caller like `makePostReq<string>(...).pipe(catchError(error => utilityService.showErrorToaster(error)))`.

Secondly, by making your call generic, I assume you intend to call it from various services/for various types of `T`. By handling errors inside `makePostReq<T>(...)` and calling `this.utilityService.showErrorToaster(e);` you have thus limited your error handling to just popping up a toast notification and nothing else. What if at one point you will need to, say redirect to an error page, and at another point you want to do something different? It will be more difficult to do so with this setup than if the callers would just to the error handling.

So I suggest you just leave it as

```js
 makePostReq<T>(reqObj: {url:string, body:any, headerData?:any}): Observable<T>{
    let headers = this.createHeaders(reqObj.headerData);
    return this.httpClient.post<T>(reqObj.url, reqObj.body, {headers:headers});
  }
```